# Nav Toggle Script Not Compatible with Page Specific Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I appreciate you taking the time to read this.

Something is conflicting between these two scripts. When I arrive at the page with HTML below, I am no longer able to toggle between pages on my site using the nav. This functionality is enabled by the first script which is loaded by each page in my site. The second script is unique to this page.

Can anybody examine this and figure why they are not compatible with each other?
Any suggestions to fix this issue would also be wonderful. You are awesome. Thank You!

HTML

```
<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Stretch</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="http://URL.net/AppPt1(revised).html">Stretch Producer</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#science">Science</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Begin page content -->
        <section id="content">
          <div id="container">
            <div id="stretch-app">
              <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="button-list">
                <ul id="stretch-nav">
                  <li id="header1" class="inactive">
                    <h2>Upper Body</h2></li>
                  <li id="front-neck" class="upper">Front Neck</li>
                  <li id="abdomen" class="upper">Abdomen</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="anatomy-container">
                <img id="anatomy" class="front-neck" src="http://URL/photos/NAME.png" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="list-container">
                <ul id="container">
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </body>
```

JS script 1

```
$('nav a').on('click', function(e) {                 // User clicks nav link
  e.preventDefault();                                // Stop loading new link
  var url = this.href;                               // Get value of href

  $('nav a.current').removeClass('current');         // Clear current indicator
  $(this).addClass('current');                       // New current indicator

  $('#container').remove();                          // Remove old content
  $('#content').load(url + ' #container').hide().fadeIn('slow'); // New content
});
```

JS script 2

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li.upper").hide();
  //Enables slide toggle by clicking header button and maintains color while active
  $("#header1").on('click', function() {
    $("li.upper").slideToggle();
    var buttonState = $("li#header1").attr("class");
    if (buttonState == "inactive") {
      $("li#header1").removeClass("inactive");
      $("li#header1").addClass("active");
      $(this).css({
        "background": "#4CAF50",
        "color": "white"
      });
    } else {
      $("li#header1").removeClass("active");
      $("li#header1").addClass("inactive");
      $(this).css({
        "background": "white",
        "color": "black"
      });
    }
  });
  //Maintain button color after being clicked
  $("li.upper").on("click", function() {
    var buttonState = $(this).attr("class");
    if (buttonState == "upper inactive") {
      $(this).removeClass("upper inactive");
      $(this).addClass("upper active");
      $(this).css({
        "background": "#008CBA",
        "color": "white"
      });
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("upper active");
      $(this).addClass("upper inactive");
      $(this).css({
        "background": "white",
        "color": "black"
      });
    }
  });

  //Allows the pictures of the highlighted human anatomy to appear
  $("#button-list li").on("click", function() {
    imgClass = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#anatomy-container img").hide(); // hide all images
    $("#anatomy-container ." + imgClass).show(); //show only image that class match with button id 
  });
  $("#button-list li").on("mouseover", function() {
    imgClass = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#anatomy-container img").hide(); // hide all images
    $("#anatomy-container ." + imgClass).show(); //show only image that class match with button id 
  });
  //Updates content of <ul> container with stretches
  var myData = jsonString;
  var newContent = '';
  var selected = null;
  $('li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    selected = $(this).attr("id");
    newContent = "";
    /** Perhaps a quite different json structure could remove the for loop **/
    for (var i = 0; i < myData.stretches.length; i++) {
      if (selected == myData.stretches[i].area) {
        newContent += '<li id = "' + selected + '-img" class = "' + myData.stretches[i].area + '">';
        newContent += '<a href="' + myData.stretches[i].ref + '">'; /** ref is not defined in JSON **/
        newContent += '<img id="stretch-image" src="' + myData.stretches[i].pic + '">';
        //newContent += '<p "'+responseObject.stretches[i].name+'">';
        newContent += '</a> + </li>';
      }
    }
    console.log(newContent);
    $('#container').html(newContent);
  });
});
```

CSS

```
 body {
   padding-top: 80px;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: monaco, monospace;
 }

 h1 {
   font-size: 30px
 }

 h2 {
   font-size: 20px;
 }

 ul {
   list-style-type: none;
 }

 #header1,
 #header2 {
   background-color: white;
   color: black;
   border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
   margin: 0 0 10px 0;
 }

 #header1:hover,
 #header2:hover,
 #header1:active,
 #header2:active {
   background-color: #4CAF50;
   color: white;
 }

#stretch-app{
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height:880px;
    width: auto;
}
 .upper,
 .lower {
   background-color: white;
   color: black;
   border: 2px solid #008CBA;
   margin: 0 0 10px 0;
   padding: 10px 5px;
 }

 .upper:hover,
 .lower:hover {
   background-color: #008CBA;
   color: white;
 }

 #button-list {
     position: absolute;
 }

#stretch-nav{
    width: 300px;
   right: 500px;
}

 #highlight {
   height: 500px;
   width: 500px;
 }

 #anatomy-container {
   border: 2px solid black;
   padding: 10px;
   height: 350px;
   width: 300px;
   position: absolute;
   float: none;
   left: 350px;
   bottom: 490px;
 }

 #anatomy {
   height: 350px;
   width: 300px;
 }

 #list-container {
   border: 2px solid black;
   padding: 10px;
   height: 450px;
   width: 300px;
   float: none;
   position: absolute;
   left: 350px;
   top: 400px;
     overflow: auto;
 }

 #stretch-image{
     position: relative;
   right: 40px;
   height: 300px;
   width: 300px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried being more specific in the second script's $('li').click(function(e) {... selector? That'll be attaching a new click function to the navbar, and I don't think that was intended.

Comment: So what your saying is instead of using $('li') as the selector I should simply try using the id such as $('#upper')?

Comment: It would be '.upper' if you're keying off of a class instead of ID, but yes. I'd use a more complex selector like '.upper li' to make sure it attaches only to the clickable items that I actually need it on, though.

Comment: Awesome I'll give it a go. Thank You!